# Static html page import

Tags: 7, importing-exporting

I want to import static html reports generated for source code by code analysis tools like [doxygen](http://www.doxygen.nl/), [understand](http://www.scitools.com/). Is there any module that can import the html reports generated by these tools directly into drupal? I tried [import html](https://drupal.org/project/import_html) without any success. Any tried and tested procedure to achieve this feature ?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's asking for recommendations or suggestions on hosting, tools, modules, themes, distributions, books, tutorials, documentation, or other off-site resources.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with the built-in text filter named "PHP Code".  To get access to this, you need to first enable the core **PHP Filter** module (in core, but disabled by default).  Then navigate to *Home » Administration » Configuration » Content authoring  » Text formats* and allow the Administrator to use the filter named "PHP code".

Now the Administrator can create nodes that use the PHP include statement to embed static HTML pages in Drupal nodes. For example, to import a static HTML page located in the Drupal root named `static.html`, create a Basic page node with this contents:

```
<?php include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/static.html'; ?>
```

and set its text format to "PHP Filter".

Note that the "PHP code" text filter allows arbitary PHP to be embedded into nodes, so make sure that only highly trusted users have access to this filter.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can I import if there are many such file with links to each other?

Comment: I am not sure if I understand the last question, but I think the answer is "Yes". The only thing that happens with PHP include is that whatever is inside the file that is named will be included verbatim in the node.  If there are links to other static HTML files in the file, then those links will be included along with everything else in the file.